# How can I return grouped sums with the reduce method based on an if condition inside it?

Tags: javascript

I want to run `reduce` to get an object with two properties based on the `option` property in the input objects. Please check my code below and expected output below:

I have data as below snippet:

```js
const data = [
   {
      "id":215,
      "option":"PP",
      "amount":50
   },
   {
      "id":215,
      "option":"PP",
      "amount":100
   },
   {
      "id":215,
      "option":"VP",
      "amount":250
   }
];

const result = data.reduce((prevValue, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue.option == 'PP') {
        prevValue += currentValue.amount;
    }
    return prevValue;
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Currently this returns the sum for only the "PP" option, but I want to get it for both options in one result object.

### Expected output

```
{
    "Total PP" => 150,
    "Total VP" => 250
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want an object to be returned from the call to `reduce`, you should pass an object as initial value to it. And then differentiate between the two categories using dynamic property access:

```js
const data = [{"id":215,"option":"PP","amount":50},{"id":215, "option":"PP","amount":100},{"id":215, "option":"VP","amount":250}];

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc["Total " + item.option] += item.amount;
    return acc;
}, { "Total PP": 0, "Total VP": 0 });

console.log(result);
```

This assumes that the `option` properties will only have those two values. If this is not the case, you'll need to make the update conditional:

```js
const data = [{"id":215,"option":"PP","amount":50},{"id":215, "option":"PP","amount":100},{"id":215, "option":"VP","amount":250}];

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if ("Total " + item.option in acc) {
        acc["Total " + item.option] += item.amount;
    }
    return acc;
}, { "Total PP": 0, "Total VP": 0 });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple problems with the code itself, i hope this works for your purpose

```
    const result = data.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
      acc[currentValue.option] += currentValue.amount;
    return acc;
  }, { PP: 0, VP: 0 });
```

Comment: My code is work well with and return only one object. So, I want to run this reduce to work only one time and return by check with option.

Comment: this case, if I want to sum option with **VP** I just write same code and change if condition if with **Option == 'VP'** and sum it again. So, I don't want write this again. let's say if I want to sum data base on 5 option so, I need to write 5 times of code below. So, I asking about other code suggestion

Comment: I understand, glad you found an answer! I updated mine for your specifik case anyways!
Usage would be "{result.VP}" or "{result.PP}"